# Ruby on Rails3: execute rails code into js.erb view, does not work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I want to do kaminari paginator dynamically

This code, handle click event to Kaminari links

Kaminari.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".paginator a").on("click", function() {
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
  });
});
```

users_controller:

```
def index
  @users = User.all(:order => "name")
  @users = Kaminari.paginate_array(@users).page(params[:page]).per(10)
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Users</h1>
<div id="users-page">
  <%= render 'users'  %>
</div>

<%= paginate @users %>
```

Then I wrote a js.erb view for users dynamically pagination:

app/views/users/index.js.erb

If I only put javascript code like

```
alert("paging");
```

when I click on paginations links, alert message perfectly.

But if I put <%= ... %> code inside, this javascript response does not execute.

```
alert("paging");
$("#users-page").html(<%= render 'users' %>)
```

either the message is displayed.

which may be the problem?

Comment: What if you JS- escape it? In any case, when saying something " doesn't work " it's helpful to include diagnostic output, like JS log messages, rendered response content, etc. Either of those should lead you to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when javascript error exists. In this case, quotation marks missing in html() function.

```
$("#users-page").html("<%= escape_javascript(render ('users')) %>")
```